FB graph API to fetch using timestamp
I am fetching ad accounts, campaigns, adsets and ads from meta business suite using graph api. I now have a pipeline to fetch it totally and it runs every week. But now i want to make a new pipeline which basically adds additional data on top of what was fetched earlier.
I am using the last fetch timestamp for each component and then extracting data from there till current and then leave a timestamp for each when the job is complete.
But when i try this, i am not able to get the additional instead i get the entire data from scratch. Is there any way i can complete this task by any other method?
i try with url = f'{base_url}{business_id}/owned_ad_accounts?access_token={access_token}&since={unix_timestamp}'
but dont get the additional data?

This question is similar to: Facebook graph SINCE and UNTIL not working. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
